# The gradient of the $l_1$ norm of the gradient of function $f(x)$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Assume $x \in R^d$ and $f(x)$ returns a scaler.

I am trying to calculate

$$\nabla_{x} \left( \|\nabla_{x} f(x)\|_1\right)$$

Is there any way to apply the chain rule and calculate this?

Comment: What does the $l_1$ norm do?

Comment: $l_1$ norm of gradient is basically the sum of the absolute value of the gradients (here $k$ gradients)

Answer (score 3):

Let $f_i(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} f(x)$ so that and similarly let $f_{ij}(x) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}f(x)$. Also I will use
$$
\text{sign}(z) = \begin{cases} 
    -1 & z < 0 \\
    0 & z = 0 \\
    1 & z > 0
\end{cases}.
$$
The gradient of a function $f$ is always given by
\begin{equation}
    \nabla f(x) = \begin{bmatrix} f_1(x) \\ f_2(x) \\ \vdots\\ f_d(x)\end{bmatrix} \end{equation}
and therefore
\begin{equation}
    ||\nabla f(x)||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^d |f_i(x)| \\
\end{equation}
Note that there are some differentiability issues if $f_i(x) = 0$ for any $i$ but I'm going to ignore those (they can be handled with sub-differentials if needed).

Recall that $$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} |z| = \text{sign}(z)
$$
(assuming you want to handle $0$ in the standard way).

Now, lets look at one partial derivative of norm.
\begin{align}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} ||\nabla f(x)||_1 &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^d |f_i(x)| \right ) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} |f_i(x)| \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^d \text{sign}(f_i(x))\cdot \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} f_i(x) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^d \text{sign}(f_i(x))\cdot  f_{ij}(x) \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^d f_{ji}(x) \text{sign}(f_i(x)) 
\end{align}
The third line is just the chain rule.
The reason I've done this last expression is because it looks a lot like a vector multiplication with the way the summation is being done over $i$. In paricular, If $H(x)$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$ at the point $x$, that is $H_{ji}(x) = f_{ji}(x)$, then the $j$th partial is the product of the $j$th row of the Hessian $H_j(x)$ and the signs of the gradient,
$$
   \frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} ||\nabla f(x)||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^d f_{ji}(x) \text{sign}(f_i(x)) = H_j(x) \cdot \text{sign}(\nabla f(x))
$$
where the sign operation is applied entrywise. From this it follows that the complete gradient is given by
\begin{align}
    \nabla || \nabla f(x)||_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 
        H_1(x) \cdot \text{sign}(\nabla f(x)) \\
        H_2(x) \cdot \text{sign}(\nabla f(x)) \\
        \vdots \\
        H_d(x) \cdot \text{sign}(\nabla f(x)) 
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 
        H_1(x) \\
        H_2(x) \\
        \vdots \\
        H_d(x)
    \end{bmatrix} \text{sign}(\nabla f(x)) = H(x) \text{sign}(\nabla f(x))
\end{align}
It's worthwhile to check for yourself that this is indeed a vector of length $d$.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}
$

If $g : \R \to \R$, then for $x \in \R^d$ let $g[x] \in \R^d$ be the result of applying $g$ to each component of $x$, i.e.
$$
  x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_d\end{pmatrix}
  \implies
  g[x] = \begin{pmatrix}g(x_1) \\ g(x_2) \\ \vdots \\ g(x_d)\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Also let $x \odot y$ be the Hadamard product of $x, y \in \R^d$, i.e.
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_d\end{pmatrix} \odot \begin{pmatrix}y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_d\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1y_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_dy_d\end{pmatrix}.
$$

We make use of two chain rules for gradients:

1. If $f : \R^d \to \R$ and $g : \R^d \to \R^d$ then
   $$
     \nabla f(g(x)) = \dot\nabla g(\dot x)\cdot\nabla_g f(g),
   $$
   where the overdots indicate that $\dot\nabla$ is only differentiating $g(\dot x)$, and I am using the convention that the inner product $\cdot$ binds more tightly than juxtaposition. Another way to write the same thing with more braces would be
   $$
     \nabla f(g(x)) = \dot\nabla\Bigl(g(\dot x)\cdot\bigl(\nabla_g f(g)\bigr)\Bigr),
   $$
2. If $f : \R^d \to \R$ and $g : \R \to \R$ then
   $$
     \nabla f(g[x]) = g'[x]\odot\bigl[\nabla_yf(y)\bigr]_{y=g[x]},
   $$
   where $g'$ is the derivative of $g$.

---

Note that the $L^1$-norm is equivalent to
$$
  ||x||_1 = ||g[x]||_2^2
$$
where $g : \R \to \R$ is given by $g(a) = \sqrt{|a|}$ and $||\cdot||_2$ is the $L^2$-norm. Using the chain rules above, we get
$$\begin{aligned}
  \nabla||\nabla f(x)||_1
&= \nabla||g[\nabla f(x)]||_2^2
\\
&= \dot\nabla\bigl[\nabla f(\dot x)\bigr]\cdot\bigl[\nabla_y||g[y]||_2^2\bigr]_{y=\nabla f(x)}
\\
&= \dot\nabla\bigl[\nabla f(\dot x)\bigr]\cdot\Bigl[g'[y]\odot\bigl[\nabla_z||z||_2^2\bigr]_{z=g[y]}\Bigr]_{y=\nabla f(x)}
\\
&= \dot\nabla\bigl[\nabla f(\dot x)\bigr]\cdot\Bigl[g'[\nabla f(x)]\odot\bigl(2g[\nabla f(x)]\bigr)\Bigr]
\end{aligned}$$
If $H_f$ is the Hessian matrix of $f$, then we can see that
$$
  \dot\nabla (\nabla f(\dot x))\cdot y = H_fy,
$$
hence
$$
  \nabla||\nabla f(x)||_1
= 2H_f\Bigl[g'[\nabla f(x)]\odot g[\nabla f(x)]\Bigr].
$$
Noting that
$$
  g'(a) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}\sqrt{|a|} = \frac{\mathrm{sign}(a)}{2\sqrt{|a|}}
$$
where $\mathrm{sign}(a)$ is the sign (-1, 0, or 1) of $a$, we compute
$$
  g'(a)g(a) = \frac{\mathrm{sign}(a)}{2\sqrt{|a|}}\sqrt{|a|} = \frac12\mathrm{sign}(a),
$$
and hence our final expression is
$$
  \nabla||\nabla f(x)||_1 = H_f\,\mathrm{sign}[\nabla f(x)].
$$

Comment: Many thanks for your solution!